# ASP.NET Bundling and Minification and using it from other web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bundle, minify

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 application that contains library of some simple jQuery widgets. Now I want to allow other web applications to use that library. Instead of inserting every widget file by file on client page it would be good to load all of them as a bundle at one request. Does anybody know is it possible to do that bundle using Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework? In other words I want to prepare some "jquery-library-1.0.0.js" file and allow other application load it.

All I can find is how to use it inside MVC application and nothing about how to prepare bundle with the static name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after some research I found the way how to do this  - using IBundleTransform interface. It allows to get access to the bundle content and I just need to dump it to the disk in the place where I want and use it later for any other applications that want to use the library.

```
public class ScriptsBundleTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public string ScriptsPath { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Minified { get; set; }
    public string Full { get; set; }

    public ScriptsBundleTransform()
    {
    }

    public ScriptsBundleTransform(string path, string version, string minified, string full)
    {
        ScriptsPath = path;
        Version = version;
        Minified = minified;
        Full = full;
    }

    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        string scriptsRoot = context.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(ScriptsPath, Version));

        if (!Directory.Exists(scriptsRoot))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(scriptsRoot);

        //  if minified file name specified...
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Minified))
        {
            using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(scriptsRoot, Minified)))
            {
                writer.Write(response.Content);
            }
        }

        //  if full file name specified...
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Full))
        {
            using (Stream writer = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(scriptsRoot, Full)))
            {
                foreach (var file in response.Files)
                {
                    file.VirtualFile.Open().CopyTo(writer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and after that I just need to add this transformer in the bundle config to the bundle that I want to dump to the disk:

```
            widgets.Transforms.Add(new ScriptsBundleTransform()
            {
                Version = "1.0.0",
                ScriptsPath = "~/Scripts",
                Minified = "jquery.library.min.js",
                Full = "jquery.library.js"
            });
```

Even if any widget in the library will be changed, dump file will be regenerated automatically and I don't have manually control this process.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it was a big help for me.  There is an issue with file locking in your code however.  You need to wrap the file.VirtualFile.Open() in a using block.

using(var virtualStream = file.VirtualFile.Open())
     {
      virtualStream.CopyTo(writer);
     }

Answer (score 0):

Bundling and Minification are the new features of the Asp.Net 4.5

You can find more details here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

So if you have the the Asp.Net 4.5 - you have the bundling and minification out of the box.
(you haven't specified the version of the Asp.Net your application is built on)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mikhail. I already checked the resource that you pointed me to. Yes, I use ASP.NET 4.5 and my question was how to save content of some bundle locally on the disk and provide direct access to it by URL something like this: /Sqripts/jquery-library-1.0.0.js instead of storing the bundle content in the cache and provide access to it by dynamically generated URL with the hash: /bundles/widgets?v=hPalLFGQkrXrW1PJWTvf4CDfMpZ54syY8BQD8_Ijzj81

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use the bundling and minification as a standalone utility but you could try one of the following:

1. If you are using the bundling and minification in a project already and just want the output JavaScript file after you launch the page in a browser you could just navigate to the URL of the file and download it.

or

1. You could look into utilities like Springboard (https://github.com/soulwire/Springboard) or Grunt ([http://gruntjs.com](http://gruntjs.com/)) though both of these will take a little extra work to get working on Windows because of their other dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I thought about the downloading the bundle content by the URL but don't like this idea cause the jQuery library is under development yet as well. To many handle work after any changes inside the library... but I'm keeping this variant in mind :)